# Proof of alternative writing of SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, svd

I'm trying to understand Singular Value Decomposition. So far I have seen the regular notation for the SVD of a matrix $A$ as
\begin{equation} 
A=USV^T
\end{equation}
But there is a second representation of the SVD of A which is
\begin{equation}
A=\sum_{\alpha} s_{\alpha}\mathbf{u}_{\alpha} \mathbf{v}_{\alpha}^T
\end{equation}
However, I have not figured out how to go from the first to the second one or why it works. How can I prove the second one from the first one?

Comment: I recommend that you go back and write down what type of object each of your symbols denotes, including dimensions of spaces they live in, and think about the definition of matrix multiplication. Edit your post to reflect what you know, what you've tried, where you get stuck _specifically_.

Comment: It is because $V$ and $U$ are unitary. Linear combinations of orthogonal complements.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to realize by considering that for any $a$ we can find $b$ so that $Vb = a$, then $USV^Ta = USV^TVb = USb$ and then consider every element in that product on it's own.

Comment: Expand $Ax=U S (V^Tx)$. This is not a trite response.